# Unable to load .vim files from subdirectory using relative paths

Tags: vim

I am trying to build a centralized VIM configuration for myself in my own "dotfiles" project, so that I can easily synchronize my VIM configuration changes between my multiple computers (ie, home and work) easily.

My thought was that I could maintain the git repo of this dotfiles project in any directory, in this case being `~/git/dotfiles/vim`. Then, this directory would contain multiple `.vim` files grouped based on the types of configuration that it offers. So, I would have a `home.vim` file that only sources other `.vim` files in this directory:

```
source plugins.vim
source keymappings.vim
...
```

The idea now is that my `~/.vimrc` file will contain nothing, except for sourcing this dotfiles project and any configuration that really is not meant to be synchronized. In my case, it is just:

```
source ~/git/dotfiles/vim/home.vim
```

Unfortunately, it looks like this type of configuration does not allow `home.vim` to load any of the files in its directory. I get the following errors when I try to run a `vim` command with this configuration set:

```
$ vim .vimrc
Error detected while processing /Users/evanbrodie/git/dotfiles/vim/home.vim:
line    1:
E484: Can't open file plugins.vim
line    2:
E484: Can't open file keymapping.vim
```

My guess is that I need to configure something to tell Vim to search for this file in the current working directory instead of needing to rely on an absolute path. I can make this conclusion based on the fact that substituting the absolute path into the `.vim` dotfiles will fix the issue. But this is not desirable, I want to rely on relative paths instead.

Comment: If you use absolute paths while sourcing it will work.

Answer (score 0):

### `runtime` command

When files are `source`d by Vim, the path is relative to the current working directory.

If you don’t want to specify a relative path, the `runtime` command can be used instead. According to the [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:runtime), this command

> Read Ex commands from {file} in each directory given by `runtimepath`
>   and/or `packpath`.

By default, the `runtimepath` in Unix is set to `$HOME/.vim, $VIM/vimfiles, $VIMRUNTIME, $VIM/vimfiles/after, $HOME/.vim/after`. This means that if your `.vim` files are in any of these directories, you can just run the following command without having to specify a directory component in the path, e.g.,

```
runtimepath plugins.vim
```

File paths can also include a directory component, e.g., I have a filetype plugin for writing emails (`~/.vim/ftplugin/mail.vim`) and it sources a file containing pre-defined abbreviations (located in `~/.vim/shared/abbreviations.vim` so they can also be used by other filetypes). This is achieved by the following line in my `ftplugin/mail.vim`:

```
runtime shared/abbreviations.vim
```